# Change counter in \edef

Tags: macros, counters

When I try to change a counter in an `\edef` using `\stepcounter`, I get a whole lot of error messages ("Missing `\endcsname` inserted"). When I try to do the same with `\addtocoutner` I get no error, but the counter remains unchanged within the `\edef`.

The following MWE produces "E, EE, F". If you remove the `%`, the errors will appear.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{testcount}
\setcounter{testcount}{5}

%\edef\foo{\Alph{testcount}\stepcounter{testcount}\Alph{testcount}}
\edef\bar{\Alph{testcount}\addtocounter{testcount}{1}\Alph{testcount}}

\begin{document}

\Alph{testcount}
,
\bar
,
\Alph{testcount}

\end{document}
```

Why is this and how can I achieve the effect that one would expect `\foo` and `\bar` to have?

Comment: you cannot make assignments (like `\stepcounter` or `\addtocounter`) in an `\edef`-like context.

Comment: `\show\bar` will show in the log: `> \bar=macro:
->E\global \advance \c@testcount 1\relax E.`

Comment: If `\bar` is defined it's fixed and  there's no action be done anymore, since the definition is expanded already. `\bar\bar\bar\bar` will do nothing but print the result (regarding `\addtocounter`

Comment: Maybe you could tell us *why* you want to do this with `\edef` in the first place? It seems really counterproductive, but perhaps you have reasons we can only guess at.

Comment: If you're only interested in the printed result use `\newcommand` instead of `\edef`.

Comment: @Christian, you are right of course, I got confused. What I should have written is that the value of the counter remains unchanged within the `\edef` and seems to only take place after it is complete. I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @clemens, is it a general TeX rule that this is not allowed in an `\edef`-ike context? If so, why? To me it seems like this should not be a problem. Oh, and I don't want to just print the result but rather save it for later use.

Comment: @schtandard assignments never are expandable. That's just the way it is.

Comment: @Harald: The reason is that I want to change the `\thesection` for a specific section to contain two section numbers (like "3. and 4."). I get the same error messages as with `\edef`, so I guess it also is an "`\edef`-like context".

Comment: @schtandard: Perhaps you should really post a document gives a clue what you want to achieve, I think this will have more success in providing a solution.

Comment: “*Why is this and how can I achieve the effect that one would expect \foo and \bar to have?*” Personally I would expect the behaviour that you get with `\def`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add `\show\bar` after doing the `\edef`, you're informed that

```
> \bar=macro:
->E\global \advance \c@testcount 1\relax E.
```

***No*** assignment is performed inside `\edef`, only macro expansion. We also have

```
% latex.ltx, line 2099:
\def\addtocounter#1#2{%
  \@ifundefined{c@#1}%
    {\@nocounterr{#1}}%
    {\global\advance\csname c@#1\endcsname #2\relax}}
```

so the first expansion replaces `\addtocounter{testcount}{1}` with that replacement text; `\@ifundefined` is expandable and, since the test returns false (because `\c@testcount` is defined), you get

```
\global\advance\csname c@testcount\endcsname 1\relax
```

The tokens `\global` and `\advance` are unexpandable, so TeX expands `\csname`, forming the token `\c@testcount`, which in turn is not expandable. So, essentially, only `\Alph{testcount}` gets really expanded, to `E` in both cases.

You can't do assignments in “pure expansion” contexts. Depending on your aim, something else can be devised.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{testcount}
\setcounter{testcount}{5}

\makeatletter
\edef\baz{%
  \Alph{testcount}\@Alph{\numexpr\value{testcount}+1\relax}%
  \unexpanded{\stepcounter{testcount}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\Alph{testcount}
,
\baz
,
\Alph{testcount}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

This answer is based on this [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304281/change-counter-in-edef#comment737806_304281).

`\bar` can be defined in two steps. First the current value of the counter is used and the expanded form saved in `\barI`. Then the counter is increased, because the assignment does not work in expandable contexts like `\edef`. The increased counter value is saved in `\barII`. Finally macro `\bar` is composed from `\barI` and `\barII`. Then `\bar` is defined with fixed and expanded counter values and let the counter untouched, when used.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{testcount}
\setcounter{testcount}{5}

\edef\barI{\Alph{testcount}}
\stepcounter{testcount}
\edef\barII{\Alph{testcount}}
\edef\bar{\barI\barII}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{testcount}{1}

\Alph{testcount},
\bar,
\Alph{testcount},
\stepcounter{testcount}{\Alph{testcount}}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a typical “ask *X* for *Y*” question.  @egreg has already explained why your approach with `\edef` is conceptually wrong.  While he was posting his answer, I was trying to write down a workaround for what you seem to indicate, in a comment, as your original problem.  I was ready to post the following attempt when I saw @egreg’s answer, essentially based on the same principle.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% \usepackage[ascii]{inputenc}

\makeatletter

\@ifdefinable\@schtandard@SavedSection{%
    \let \@schtandard@SavedSection \section
}
\newenvironment*{NonStandardSectionNumbering}{%
    \renewcommand*\thesection{%
        \@arabic{\numexpr\value{section}-\@ne\relax}
        and~\arabic{section}%
    }%
    \renewcommand*\section{%
        \stepcounter{section}%
        \@schtandard@SavedSection
    }%
}{}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

\section{Normal numbering}
\label{S:1}
This section has normal numbering.

\section{Another one}
\label{S:2}
This too.

\begin{NonStandardSectionNumbering}
    \section{Special numbering}
    \label{S:3&4}
    Inside the \texttt{NonStandardSectionNumbering} environment, however,
    sections are numbered in a different way.

    \section{And again}
    \label{S:5&6}
    Some random text.
\end{NonStandardSectionNumbering}

\section{Back to standard numbering}
\label{S:7}
This section is again numbered in the normal way.

\section{Yet another section}
\label{S:8}
Note that the progression of section numbers is correct.  The references are
correct too: section~\ref{S:1}, section~\ref{S:2}, sections \ref{S:3&4},
sections \ref{S:5&6}, section~\ref{S:7}, and section~\ref{S:8}.

\end{document}
```

Bear in mind that this is only an unfinished trial: you should specify more clearly what you want to achieve.

**Edit:**  I’ve edited the code, adding a remark about references.  I’m adding a picture that shows the output, too:

[image: Output of hte code]